# Handling events from wxTextCtrl on wxFrame - C++/wxWidgets

Tags: c++, events, user-interface, wxwidgets

I have a `MyFrame` which derives from `wxFrame`. A `wxTextCtrl` is added to this frame. Can I handle `EVT_KEY_DOWN` of this text control in frame? Something like,

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(wxTextCtrl, wxControl)
    EVT_KEY_DOWN(MyFrame::OnKeyDown)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

The above code seems to be not working. Documentation says events like this can only be handled by the object where the event is originated. So should I subclass `wxTextCtrl` to handle this and somehow send the information to frame?

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wxCommandEvent` and `wxNotifyEvent` type events from a child controls are set to propagate upward to the parent frame automatically. However, the `wxKeyEvent` is derived from the `wxEvent` so it is not propagating to the parent frame. Well, you may use dynamic event handlers to route some of the events to any of `wxEvtHandler` derived objects.

Under wxWidgets 2.8 you should use `wxEvtHandler::Connect`. This method is described [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlerconnect). You may also look at [this sample code](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Example_Of_Using_Connect_For_Events).

Under wxWidgets 2.9 and SVN you should use `wxEvtHandler::Bind<>`:

```
MyFrame::MyFrame(...)
{
    m_textcontrol->Bind(wxEVT_KEY_DOWN, &MyFrame::OnTextControlKeyDown, this);
}
```

The `wxEvtHandler::Bind<>` method is described [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html#overview_events_bind).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, subclass wxtextCtrl to handle the key presses in the parent frame.

```
class cSpecialTextCtrl : public wxTextCtrl
{
public:
  cSpecialTextCtrl( ... ) : wxTextCtrl( ... ) {}
  void OnKeyDown( wxKeyEvent& ev );
private:
  DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};
```

and of course

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE( cSpecialTextCtrl , wxTextCtrl)
    EVT_KEY_DOWN( cSpecialTextCtrl ::OnKeyDown)
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

In the method, pass the event to your MyFrame

```
void cSpecialTextCtrl::OnKeyDown( wxKeyEvent& ev )
{
  ((MyFrame*)GetParent())->OnKeyDown( ev );
}
```