# Can't get EVT_KEY_DOWN to fire in wxPerl

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, wxperl

In this case `$self` is a subclass of `Wx::Frame` and I can add controls, menus, etc to the frame.  However I cannot add key events.  I am using the following to add the key event:

```
  EVT_KEY_DOWN($self,  \&_process_char);
```

The _process_char function looks like this:

```
sub _process_char {
   my ($evt) = @_;
   warn 'key pressed';
}
```

The event doesn't fire.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I get key down events to work with wxperl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with event propagation -- a textctrl handles keydown/keyup events, and the default one (**default textctrl handler**) won't propagate these events UP to a frame. If you want your handler to be called **bind to wxTheApp() or the textctrl**. Here is an example where not all keys are propagated

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict; use warnings;
use Wx ();

Main( @ARGV );
exit( 0 );

sub Main {
    local $|  = 1;
    my $app   = Wx::SimpleApp->new;
    my $frame = Wx::Frame->new( undef, -1, "type stuff ", ([250,150])x2 );
    my $text  = Wx::TextCtrl->new( $frame, -1,"", );

    $app->SetTopWindow( $frame );

    my $target = @_ ? $frame : $text;
    Wx::Event::EVT_KEY_DOWN( $target ,  \&Frobnicate );
    Wx::Event::EVT_KILL_FOCUS($app,  sub{  Wx::wxTheApp()->ExitMainLoop });

    $app->{counter} = 0;
    $frame->Show;
    $text->SetFocus;
    $app->MainLoop;
}

sub Frobnicate {
    my( $widget, $kev )=@_;
    my $app   = Wx::wxTheApp();
    my $count = $app->{counter}++;
    my $frame = $app->GetTopWindow;
    my $title = $frame->GetTitle;
    $title =~ s{\d*+$}{$count};
    $frame->SetTitle( $title );
    $kev->Skip if 0 == $count % 4; ## sometimes :P
}
```

- http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_events.html
- http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_key_event.html
- [Handling events from wxTextCtrl on wxFrame - C++/wxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813693/handling-events-from-wxtextctrl-on-wxframe-c-wxwidgets)
- [wxWidgets Discussion Forum • View topic - Impossible to catch EVT_KEY_DOWN or EVT_CHAR in a wxPanel](http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=21262)
- **http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Catching_key_events_globally**

Also, you call your handler **_process_char** but you use EVT_KEY_DOWN -- there is an EVT_CHAR just for chars :)

**update**: For notebook example replace (in above sample) around `$text` with

```
    my $noteb = Wx::Notebook->new( $frame );
    my $text  = Wx::TextCtrl->new( $noteb, -1,"", );
    $noteb->AddPage( $text, "you myst type stuff");
    Wx::Event::EVT_KEY_DOWN( $app,  \&Frobnicate );
```

Comment: Does the notebook control fail to propagate keyboard events up?  If so that may be my problem.  I am having trouble debugging though.

Comment: No, its a window just like a frame, it will propagate keyboard events up (all the ones it doesn't handle). But whatever you're doing, you can always bind to the `$app` and that should work. `If my answers aren't helping, you should post code that demonstrates your problem.`

Comment: Answer accepted, but... I found that what I was trying to do was wrong and so I abandoned this method altogether.  Apparently ctrl-key commands are best fired from menubars on windows.....  so it didn't solve my problem but more for reasons beyond the scope fo your question.